# Dealing with stealth

Tags: hearthstone

Stealthed minions can be a pain, since the enemy or you yourself, can "save" a stealthed minion on the field, to make a finishing move to your hero or another minion.

**What are some effective ways to deal with a stealthed minion for any class or every Hero class?**

Comment: Spells that affect 'All'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I deal with stealthed minions in one of 3 ways.

#### Area of effect

Flamestrike, holy nova, fan of knives, doomsayer, etc. can all damage stealth minions, however, the damage they do is not always enough. Mass silence can also help.

#### Random target spells

Spells that have a random target, such as deadly shot for the hunter deal have a chance to deal with a stealth minion quite nicely. The less minions the enemy has on the board the better (usually).

#### Taunts

Taunts will force the stealth creature to attack it instead of something you want to stay alive. The opposing player could quite easily get rid of your taunt, though, and it doesn't work against minions, who are not made to attack, such as blood imps.

Comment: If your oppponent has only the stealthed minion, the "random" spell becomes a pretty targeted one, as well.

Comment: don't forget the hunter has flare, which reveals stealth.

Comment: What do you mean by stealth taunts?

Comment: @Lyrion You can buff a stealth creature with taunt using sunfury protector or defender of argus (unless they patched it at some point and I missed it)

Comment: @3ventic Yes I know, but they are useless while they are under stealth, they still count as stealth and not a taunt. I've had it bug out tho that I couldn't attack because of the stealth taunt. But normally they don't count as taunt then.

Comment: @Lyrion Ah, yeah, must have been a bug then.

Comment: @Lyrion that was a bug present in the beta, then it was fixed. Now a stealth taunt minion shows the "taunt shield" as semi-transparent, giving a visual clue that the taunt will become active once the minion loses stealth.

Comment: There are a few various misc cards that don't fit into those categories too, such as Betrayal.

Comment: @SLC It's *sort of* area of effect, though, hitting 2-3 enemy minions (depends whether you count the betrayer)