# Which cards can affect a stealthed minion?

Tags: hearthstone

In Hearthstone, there are several cards that have stealth, which means you cannot target those minions. What puzzles me, is that some AoE cards seem to not affect some stealth cards. Did I run into a bug or is this intended and what are the combinations that affect each other?

[image: Screenshot of knob minion]

While the minion on the screenshot was affected by my Arcane Explosion, I ran into other minions that are not, but I don't remember them all.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/164233/dealing-with-stealth

Comment: @3ventic running "hearthstone stealth" as search string did not return that question. /r/shittyprogramming

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Stealth](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Stealth) cards cannot be directly targeted by your enemy. This means they can't target it for attack, or cast a spell on it, or use a targeted effect on it.

However, it is NOT immune to untargeted effects. There are three types of untargeted effects:

- **Full-Board**: Cards like [Arcane Explosion](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Arcane_Explosion) ("Deal 1 damage *to all enemy minions*.") that affect an entire side of the board.
- **Area of Effect**: Cards like [Betrayal](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Betrayal) ("Force an enemy minion to deal its damage *to the minions next to it*.") that affect minions based on position.
- **Random**: Cards like [Knife Juggler](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Knife_Juggler) ("After you summon a minion, deal 1 damage *to a random enemy*.") that affect a random minion.

Stealth does not affect you; that is, you are able to target your own stealthed minions at will.

Similar to Stealth is Untargetable (for lack of an official term), an effect shared by [Faerie Dragon](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Faerie_Dragon) and [Laughing Sister](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Laughing_Sister). Untargetable minions can still be hit by untargeted effects. Unlike Stealth minions, however, they can be targeted by minion effects (Elven Archer's damage, Spellbreaker's silence, etc.), but not by the player that owns them.

As for your claim that some minions were not affected by Arcane Explosion — is it possible that they had [Divine Shield](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Divine_Shield) or were under the effect of [Commanding Shout](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Commanding_Shout)?

Comment: Note that Faerie Dragon and Laughing Sisters, unlike stealthed creatures, *can* be targetted by minion effects.

Comment: Sepp2k's ceomment should be added as part of the answer.